# Adding spaces before a string - not functioning like I assumed it would

Tags: java, concatenation

I'm familiar with concatenation, it's a simple enough concept. What I'm trying to do it right-align a few numbers using a simple substring method. Here's what I have, hopefully that will explain it better:

```
String a1 = "    " + "" + a;
String e1 = "    " + "" + e;
String i1 = "    " + "" + i;
String o1 = "    " + "" + o;
String u1 = "    " + "" + u;

System.out.println ("The file contained:");
System.out.println ("A: " +  a1.substring(4));
System.out.println ("E: " +  e1.substring(4));
System.out.println ("I: " +  i1.substring(4));
System.out.println ("O: " +  o1.substring(4));
System.out.println ("U: " +  u1.substring(4));
```

I've omitted the rest of the code, because it's not relevant to my question (and works fine).

What I was hoping this would do is concatenate a,e,i,o,and u with 4 'spaces'. When I run the program, there is no sign of any spaces before a,e,i,o, or u.

Any help or input is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT*: I should clarify. I want the last 4 characters of the string, hence the a1.substring(4);.

EDIT 2: I'm an idiot. This was a really simple overlook on my part. Correct code that right-aligns using substring:

```
     String a1 = "    " + a;
     String e1 = "    " + e;
     String i1 = "    " + i;
     String o1 = "    " + o;
     String u1 = "    " + u;
  System.out.println ("The file contained:");
  System.out.println ("A: " +  a1.substring(a1.length() - 4));
  System.out.println ("E: " +  e1.substring(e1.length() - 4));
  System.out.println ("I: " +  i1.substring(i1.length() - 4));
  System.out.println ("O: " +  o1.substring(o1.length() - 4));
  System.out.println ("U: " +  u1.substring(u1.length() - 4));
```

Comment: All those substring calls remove all the spaces.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is right-allign integers, you can do it with `printf` like this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 100;
System.out.printf("A:%20d\n", a);
System.out.printf("B:%20d\n", b);
```

Output:

```
A:                  10
B:                 100
```

Edit after edit in question.

To take the last four characters of a string do

```
s.substring(s.length()-4)
```

Comment: How would I do it with the substring method, though? I'm more than sure your way is more efficient but the assignment calls for using the substring method.

Comment: See edit. `substring()` takes as a parameters the starting index of the sub-string to keep. To take the last four characters, subtract 4 from the `length()` of the string

Comment: Hmm. I read (and have done this) that if you only include one integer in the parameter it'll go from that point to  the end of the string. I  can do it the long way though, hopefully that works. EDIT:  I'm an idiot. I just realized what you mean. Gah, that's really simple. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use spaces you can do:

```
String a1 = "    " + a;
String e1 = "    " + e;
String i1 = "    " + i;
String o1 = "    " + o;
String u1 = "    " + u;

System.out.println ("The file contained:");
System.out.println ("A: " +  a1);
System.out.println ("E: " +  e1);
System.out.println ("I: " +  i1);
System.out.println ("O: " +  o1);
System.out.println ("U: " +  u1);
```

Comment: But user000001's answer will right align everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
String a1 = "    " + "" + a;
String e1 = "    " + "" + e;
String i1 = "    " + "" + i;
String o1 = "    " + "" + o;
String u1 = "    " + "" + u;

System.out.println ("The file contained:");
System.out.println ("A: " +  a1.substring(0, 4));
System.out.println ("E: " +  e1.substring(0, 4));
System.out.println ("I: " +  i1.substring(0, 4));
System.out.println ("O: " +  o1.substring(0, 4));
System.out.println ("U: " +  u1.substring(0, 4));
```

substring(4) prints exactly the 4th index of the string
substring(0,4) prints from index 0 to the 4th one.